Are there circular reasoning in these explanations?
Other people have minds like mine because:
1.
Other people have minds like mine:

other people are biologically very similar to me

the behavior of other people is very similar to my behavior.

my mind is responsible for my behavior.

the simplest and most understandable explanation is that other people have minds that are responsible for their behavior.


This is the principle of uniformity of nature and it preserves symmetry.
2.
Other people have minds like mine:
Is a simpler and clearer explanation because it offers one mechanism to explain my behavior and the behavior of other people.
3.
Other people have minds like mine:
Is a simpler and more understandable explanation, because it does not make me special among other people who are biologically very similar to me and have very similar behavior.
4.
Other people have minds like mine:

I am a human being.

My mind is responsible for my behavior.

From my own case, I know what the behavior of a person who has a mind should be.

Other people look a lot like me and have behaviors very similar to mine.

Other people behave as people who have minds should behave, so the simplest and most understandable explanation for other people's behavior would be that other people have minds like mine.


Alternative explanations are complex and confusing because they suggest that other people behave as if they have minds when in fact they do not.
5.
Other people have minds like mine:
This explanation makes much more sense and is much more understandable because the behavior of other people is explained by the fact that all people have mental states such as desires, motivations, beliefs, thoughts, emotions and other mental states thanks to which other people interact with each other, create relationships, they help each other, communicate, share their impressions, ideas, feelings, thoughts, develop, eat, sleep, have fun, take offense, take care of themselves, etc.
Solipsism does not make sense and is incomprehensible because it claims that my mind controls the behavior of other people. That is, people have fun, communicate, interact with each other, eat, sleep, share their impressions, etc., not because they have mental states that are responsible for their behavior, but because my mind controls their behavior with the help of an unknown mechanism that copies my behavior in similar situations.
Explain whether there is circular reasoning in my explanations.
Tell me if there are any mistakes in my explanations?
Maybe some logical errors?
Is it reasonable to use these justifications for believing in the existence of other minds?
Thank you

To the last question: it is perfectly reasonable. We use thus pattern of reasoning every day.

Is there circular reasoning involved?

It seems not... But this does not mean that the arguments prove.

Explain a little more. Are there any circular reasoning in my arguments? If they are, then the argument must be invalid. Am I understanding correctly?

It is not clear what you want from this question!

Are there circular reasoning in the arguments I have given?


An AI agent may have similar behaviour, but it does not have a mind.

Why not include animals too, so you have one simple explanation for everything. It does not work.

It makes sense.

It does not feel like reasoning to me, but a set of observations.

Behavioural explanation, I like it.




Artificial intelligence will be a more difficult explanation because it violates the principle of uniformity and symmetry for no reason whatsoever. 2. I didn't understand. Explain. What about 4 and 5?



This applies only to humans. Animals differ in structure and behavior. 4. This is the same as: since it looks like a duck, walks like a duck, and quacks like a duck, it must be a duck until there is no reason to doubt it.



Artificial intelligence will divide me and others for no reason.

